# MySQL optimize select count distinct group by

Tags: mysql

I have  this query:

```
SELECT `variationID`, count(DISTINCT(`userID`)) 
FROM data WHERE `testID` = XXXX AND `visit` = 1  GROUP BY `variationID`
;
```

that takes a lot of time to query.How I can speed up the query.

> select_type table type possible_keys   key     key_len     ref       rows 
>   filtered   Extra  SIMPLE         data
>   ref   dc3_testIDPage,dc3_testIDvarIDPage,user_test_varID_url
>   dc3_testIDvarIDPage    8   const   33106102    100.00  Using where

This is the output of the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `userID` bigint(17) NOT NULL,
   `testID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `variationID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `url` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `visit` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `isTestPage` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`testID`),
   KEY `url` (`url`),
   KEY `dc3_testIDPage` (`testID`,`url`),
   KEY `dc3_testIDvarIDPage` (`testID`,`variationID`,`url`),
   KEY `user_test_url` (`userID`,`testID`,`url`),
   KEY `user_test_varID_url` (`userID`,`testID`,`variationID`,`url`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67153224 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for posting the EXPLAIN plan. Can you also edit your post above to add the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE data`? To format it as a code block, highlight it and use `ctl-k` or the `{}` editor toolbar button.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do to speed up your query is to make sure you are not doing full table scans. All the columns in your where clause should appear in indexes. So in your case testID and visit should have indexes and even better you can create a single index with both testID and visit. If visit is a true/false boolean that won't help narrow the index search much but testID certainly will.

Create index documentation is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Based on the create table you have id and testID are in a single primary key. Add a new key or index that only has testID in it. That should help quite a bit. Since it looks like visit is not a boolean adding an index with both visit and testID will give you the best performance boost.

Comment: Thanks MBA but with the contrainst in the production and space we cannot add more index in the database;Any other option to re writ the query to have more performance?

Comment: @oasi711 whatever else you may do as long as a full table scan is happening that full table scan will dominate performance. I see you have five secondary indexes. Do you need them all? If space is a major consideration too then I would recommending doing an analysis of which indices are most important and prioritizing.